# Every `aex` have a `aex.0` in my QFX5100, why?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

When i show interface terse in my Juniper switch qfx5100:

```
....
ae29                    up    up
ae29.0                  up    up   inet     192.168.9.2/24
ae30                    up    up
ae30.0                  up    up   eth-switch
ae31                    up    up
ae31.0                  up    up   eth-switch
ae32                    up    up
ae32.0                  up    up   eth-switch
ae33                    up    up
ae33.0                  up    up   eth-switch
ae35                    up    up
ae35.0                  up    up   eth-switch
```

you see every `aex` have a `aex.0`, why ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's default behavior on Juniper devices.

From documentation:

> Configure a logical interface on the physical device. You must configure a logical interface to be able to use the physical device.

So, from this point we firstly set two or more interfaces as aggregated

> aeX

and after we determine logical interface aeX.0 with needed settings.

Also from documentation [inet(interfaces)](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/configuration-statement/inet-edit-interfaces-unit-family-qfx-series.html):

> You must configure a logical interface to be able to use the physical
>   device.